# How to convert a source object list to a resultant object list using rxJava

Tags: java, android, transform, rx-java, listobject

I have a list `List<User>` of User

```
public class User
{
  int a;
  String b;
}
```

And i have another `List<MinorUser>`

```
public class MinorUser
{
   int a;
   String b;
}
```

I want to add `List<MinorUser>` to `List<User>` by converting `List<MinorUser>` to `List<User>`

Is there any way to do this using `RxJava`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RxJava, add them directly.

```
List<User> users;
List<MinorUser> mUsers;
mUsers.forEach(mu -> users.add(new User(mu.a, mu.b)));
```

RxJava

```
Observable.from(mUsers)
    .map(mu -> new User(mu.a, mu.b))
    .forEach(users::add);
```